# Laravel - Cannot print_r paginated collection - Memory Issue

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, out-of-memory, eloquent

In laravel 4.1, when I paginate a collection, I am unable to print_r or var_dump the collection without `->toArray()`.

I just get a white screen of death `wsod`.

I get the same problem using both Eloquent and QueryBuilder

Example Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $products = $this->product->with('category')->paginate(5);
return View::make('admin.products.index', compact('products'));
}
```

Example View Doesnt work

```
<pre><?php print_r($products); ?></pre>
```

Example View Does Work

```
<pre><?php print_r($products->toArray()); ?></pre>
```

The only feedback I get is from my `laravel.log` file

```
[2014-01-27 14:50:34] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 130023424 bytes)' in /Applications/AMPPS/www/testapp.lar/app/storage/views/18e32e837eb584960d223cd8728fd06e:38
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleShutdown()
#1 {main} [] []
```

Does anybody know what's going on with this massive consumption of memory or how to fix?

Comment: It appears you already know how to fix... use `toArray()`!

Comment: You attempt to print that object together with all its internal data. Useless. `toArray()` or `toJson()` to the rescue!

Comment: This doesn't make sense... What extra data? An extra few fields? I am trying to find out how I should access the paginated data within my view. As such, I am using `print_r($products);` because $products->total or `$products->per_page` doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

When you print_r($products) you are essentially printing the massive object that Laravel uses to query and fetch the data.  You'll basically get a massive amount of text, which is obviously overwhelming your machine.  You don't need/want that.

You want to iterate the $products collection and let Laravel magically return the values.

```
foreach ( $products as $v ) {
    echo $v->product_name;
}
```

If you prefer to work with arrays then you can convert the $products collection to an array and iterate that.

```
$products = $products->toArray();

foreach ( $products['data'] as $v ) {

}
```

When you convert the paginated collection to an array, the array will be structured as follows, thus the reference to ['data'] above.

Array
(
    [total] => ...
    [per_page] => ...
    [current_page] => ...
    [last_page] => ...
    [from] => ...
    [to] => ...
    [data] => array(...)
)

Comment: Thanks. Just to confirm... Does that mean that I **must** convert the object to an array in order to access pagination info?? There is no way to access this info through the default $products object?